# How to test webservice simulating several concurrent requests

Tags: asp.net, web-services, visual-studio, testing, stress-testing

I've got this situation.
I need to test a web application that was created with asp.net and c#.

This application has one special process that does the heaviest and the most important process in all the application. This process is part of the webservice that I need to test.

Now I've been asked to come up with any kind of program to simulate a specific number of simultaneous requests to the process, to see how it reacts to a certain number of user trying to call and use the same process.

I've never done anything like this before, but some ideas have come to mind, like maybe creating a little program in visual studio using the BackgroundWorker class and in this backgroundworker call the webservice , then call this backgroundworker the number of times specified by the user.

As I mentioned, I've never done anything similar, so I'm open to suggestions.

What would you do if you had do something similar?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182594.aspx

Comment: @Donal but that requires VS Ultimate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performing a Stress Test on Web Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492/performing-a-stress-test-on-web-application)

Answer (score 1):

Don't write this yourself, go straight to a web load testing tool.

See also
[Performing a Stress Test on Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492/performing-a-stress-test-on-web-application)